# Does @Cacheable#cacheNames have nothing to do with Redis?

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis

I annotated my service as follows

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = {"some"},
           key = "{#req.some, #req.other, #req.property}")
public List<Some> listSome(SomeReq req) {
    ..
}
```

It seems work and I saw these keys via Medis.
(`coupon` is the value of `spring.cache.redis.key-prefix`.)

```
coupon{Some},{Other},{Property}
coupon{Some},{Other},{Property}
coupon{Some},{Other},{Property}
coupon{Some},{Other},{Property}
coupon{Some},{Other},{Property}
coupon{Some},{Other},{Property}
```

Where was the `cacheNames` in action?

Is it possible to collide if I add other service method with same pattern of keys?

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = {"someOther"},
           key = "{#req.some, #req.other, #req.property}")    
List<SomeOther> listSomeOthers(SomeOtherReq req) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering for my own question for further reachers.

Simply, I need to defined a bean for a `RedisCacheManager` to make the `cacheNames` works.

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RedisCacheManager cacheManager = RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(defaultCacheConfig())
            .build();
    return cacheManager;
}
```

As you can see I didn't change anything from `defaultCacheConfig()`.

And the keys are property prefixed with `{cacheName}::`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to collide if I add other service method with same pattern of keys?

No because `cacheNames` are (work like) namespaces so you can use same keys in different namespaces.

Comment: Is this really a true fact even with Redis?

Comment: if you take a look at Redis keys `$keys *`, you can see that each key has the `cacheName` prepended.

Comment: No, I don't see any prepended `cacheNames` value from the `KEYS '*'`. Are we talking about Spring?

Comment: I finally got it. I need to define a bean for `RedisCacheManager`.

Comment: Sorry about `keys *`, I usually use Spring Boot which provides a default cache configuration with cacheName prepended on each key.